# How can I change the behavior for python-shell-send-buffer?

Tags: python

I am using the default **python.el** python-mode for my Python development in Emacs. When I run the command `python-shell-send-buffer` with `C-c C-c`, it prompts me by default with:

**Run Python:** /usr/bin/python -i

I would like this to default to `/usr/bin/python3` without the `-i` option. Is there a variable where I can set for the path that shows up for the `python-shell-send-buffer` command? I have looked through the completions for `python-shell-` but couldn't find what I am looking for. Thank you!

Comment: This don't work. When you type C-c C-c, Emacs still use Python2 interpreter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`python-shell-interpreter` is a variable defined in `python.el`. Its [default] value is **"python"**.

```
Documentation: Default Python interpreter for shell.

You can customize this variable.
```

---

`python-shell-interpreter-args` is a variable defined in `python.el`.  Its [default] value is **"-i"**.

```
Documentation:  Default arguments for the Python interpreter.

You can customize this variable.
```